# Angular 2 provide generic interface

Tags: angular, typescript

i have this generic interface and implementation:

```
   export interface IConverter<T, C> {
    convert(from: T): C;
}

export class ColorConverter implements IConverter<string, string>{
    convert(from: string): string {
        return "";
    }

}
```

I can use ColorConvert in component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: '',
  providers: [{ provide: IConverter, useClass: ColorConverter }]
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(private colorConverter: ColorConverter) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

I have error in `provide:IConverter`:

> 'IConverter' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

How to provide generic interface? Thanks

Comment: There is not duplicate, i resolve different problem. I have generic interface and its not working

Comment: No, it's the same. *In order to be used as both an interface and provider token, it may be abstract class*. This is what the answer says. There's no such thing as interface in JS output. You can't use interface for anything but typing.

Comment: Ok, I didnt understand it. Thanks